# how to "chain" selector together and apply the same function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Maybe the title didn't really state what my question is.

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li class="test">C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

what I am trying to do is apply background colour to the adjacent siblings of an element with class "test", and itself as well, totally three of them will have a background colour.
so i have to do the following.

```
    $('ul li.test').each(function(){
        $(this).prev().css('background','red');
        $(this).css('background','red');
        $(this).next().css('background','red');
    });
```

which i reckon it is a pretty ugly coding.
Is there a way to do something like $(prev, this, next).somefunction()
thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you provide some more details on what you're about to do? Maybe it can be done with pure css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.add()` to add elements to the set of matched elements:

```
$(this).add($(this).prev()).add($(this).next()).css('background','red');
```

Or with `.addBack()` (`.andSelf()` for jQuery versions before 1.8):

```
$(this).prev().addBack().next().addBack().css('background','red');
```

Comment: @Dom: Too many API changes... Thanks, I didn't know they did that.

Answer (score 1):

use [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

```
$(this).prev().css('background','red')
       .end().css('background','red')
       .next().css('background','red');
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, but by doing this way, i still have to manage three css styles which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to cache the selection and apply the styling to it.

```
var $this = $(this);
var elements = $this;
elements.add($this.prev());
elements.add($this.next());

elements.css('background','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compact two of them together using the [Next Adjacent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)

```
$(".test, .test + li").css("background-color","#F00");
```

I also tried tried `$("li + .test")` as well, but that wasn't working for me

Edit:

`$("li + .test")` does work, but it selects the `.test` element. There doesn't seem to be a previous adjacent selector though

Hope this helps

Comment: You are right, there isn't a previous adjacent selector. Usually selectors flow downwards but not upwards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I would maybe try to join some css practice with jQuery and do it this way:

**CSS**

```
.test,
.test + li {
  background: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.test').prev().css('background','red');
```

But I wonder myself if there's cleaner solution. :)